# How to calculate UISlider values from any range to a range 0-1.0

Tags: ios, math, uislider

I have a UISlider with variable minimum- and maximum settings.
Now I need to calculate the value to a range from 0 to 1.0.
For example:
minimum = -50.0
maximum = -20.0

The result should be with value -50.0 = 0.0, value -20.0 = 1.0
A value of -35.0 is propably about 0.5

Also I need to calculate it from rage 0-1.0 to range above, so 0.5 should return -35.0.

I don't know why this question is off-topic. It doesn't need sample-code to explain math things principical. Anyway, its answered without any confusion.

Comment: Basically you said yourself why the question is off-topic: "*doesn't need sample-code to explain math things principical*" Obviously, your question is about basic math and not about programming. Also, note that there is no question in your question. There is only *should be* and *need to*, which people read as *give me code because I'm too lazy to write my own* regardless if this is true or not. A good on-topic question for this place could for example be something like "I tried to convert slider values by doing {example}, but instead of 0-1 I get {result}. Where is the mistake?"

Answer (score 2):

The range you want is 30 integers wide, so first multiply the slider value by 30. Now your range is `0...30`. Then subtract 50 from the slider value. Now your range is `-50...-20`.

And for the reverse, add 50 to get back to the range `0...30`, then divide by 30 for the range `0...1`.

Comment: thanks. Thats the reverse way from range `0...1.0` to `-50...-20`. How about fram range `-50...-20` to `0...1.0`?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the conversion. Then you'll need to do the reverse: add 50, divide by 30.

Answer (score 0):

selectedValue = -35.0(from answer)

```
let slideValue = (selectedValue - minValue)/(maxValue - minVlaue)
```

sliderValue = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

try calculations like this:

```
var updatedNormalizedValue: Float

@IBAction func valuechanged(_ slider: UISlider) {
    let min = slider.minimumValue
    let max = slider.maximumValue
    let interval = max - min
    updatedNormalizedValue = (slider.value - min) / interval
}
```